# Magento2 cloud Setup multiple issue

Tags: magento2, nginx, google-cloud

The website constantly give 502 error whenever tries to edit any product or upload a product

error: Lock tables although only a single query is running

[image]

Next error:

When i check Nginx access logs & opens a page from backend most of the time I see `session/unlogin` request there & actual request never logging in & web page throws a 502 error.

[image]

Server Details :

- Google kubernestes engine (load balancer ingress)
- Nginx
- PHP FPM
- Mysql (google cloud sql)

Comment: i wonder what motivates people when they decide to change the default admin path. but for your issue - please check **error log**. not access log.

Answer (score 0):

Its a 502 error. Which means a `Bad Gateway`. Please check your error and system log. You can find many logs at `<yourmagentowebsite>/var/log`  folder. Also check your server log.

Comment: Nothing gets recorded in any of the files in  /var/log. 
Checked the logging as well & it's on